# Knockout sortable breaking when moving up array

Tags: jquery-ui, ko.observablearray, knockout-sortable

Has anyone ever seen this? I am using knockout sortable and when I grab an LI element in my OL and drag it up the screen effectively moving it from a higher element in the knockout array to a lower element (move from 4 to 0) everything works fine.

However when I move from 0 up to 4 every item that is passed over seems to lose its knockout id in the markup when I look at it instead of the items having an attribute **ko29481270e89u012987**="ko234" it just reads null.

This only happens in IE8 and I am using:

knockout-sortable 0.8.1
jquery-ui 1.10.x
jquery 1.10.x
knockout 2.2.1

In latest Chrome, Firefox and IE9 there are no issues. I should also say that the page
that contains the sortable list is being hosted in SharePoint.

Comment: Never figured this out so we just removed the drag and drop and added up down bumping buttons. Now I am just splicing the array and shifting the item I want to move up and down the array which is working fine, but I would have liked to have the drag and drop for some of the bigger models.

Comment: I suppose there is no way that you can reproduce this in jsFiddle?  Are you using named templates or anonymous inside of the sortable binding?  If you are using a named template, make sure that the named template contains a single container element with no whitespace/line feeds around it. I have seen that help in older IE.